# Saving a UIView as an Image causes zPositioning of its Subviews to Fail

Tags: swift

I need to save a view in my app as a .png image. The view contains 4 subviews each on a different layer via zPosition - subview.layer.zPosition.

mainView -

- subview 1 (UITextView) - zPosition = 0
- subview 2 (UITextView) - zPosition = 1
- subview 3 (UITextView) - zPosition = 2
- subview 4 (UITextView) - zPosition = 3

I have the following extension function to UIView. The image saves but is ignoring the zPositioning of the subviews. Suvbviews are stacked on top of each other in the wrong order in the resultant saved image. The code I have is as follows:

```
extension UIView {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
            return renderer.image { rendererContext in
                layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
var snapshot: UIImage? = mainView.asImage()
```

After some Googling I found that manually reordering the subviews and then calling rendererContext on each one can fix this problem. It works on the zPositioning with all elements now stacking correctly but all elements now lose their x/y positioning in relation to the mainView. I can see this is due to the fact that the main view is now being ignored but I'm struggling with how I can fix this. Can anybody help?

```
extension UIView {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
            return renderer.image { rendererContext in
                let orderedLayers = self.subviews.sorted(by: {
                    $0.layer.zPosition < $1.layer.zPosition
                })
                for l in orderedLayers {
                    l.layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
                }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out so in case anybody else comes across this problem the solution was to add each newly ordered layer back into the parent view (self in this case as the parent view calls the extension function). The modified code is below:

```
func asImage() -> UIImage {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            let orderedLayers = self.subviews.sorted(by: {
                $0.layer.zPosition < $1.layer.zPosition
            })
            for l in orderedLayers {
                self.addSubview(l)
            }
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        } 
    }
}
```